# AWS EC2 unable to SSH with Key Pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having some problems using SSH to get into my running AWS EC2 instance. According to the instructions, I need to create a Key Pair, which downloads a `.pem` private key file, which I have named `QARTH.pem`. From the directory where this file has been saved, I'm supposed to execute command:

```
ssh -i "QARTH.pem" ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazon.com
```

However, I get the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm using the auto-generated `launch-wizard` security group, which allows port 22 incoming access to all IPs.

I've also used the example procedure to convert the `.pem` file to a PuTTy private key `.ppk` file, and used the PuTTy client. I get the same error.

This seems like a pretty straightforward procedure, so I don't know what I could be doing wrong. If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear them. However, I'm not strong in network security, so please make responses lay-person friendly.

Answer (score 1):

You are either using the wrong key pair (QARTH.pem), the wrong username, connecting to the wrong system or QARTH.pem is not set to be read-only.

**STEP 1: Add debugging options to ssh to help determine what is wrong:**

```
ssh -v -i QARTH.pem ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazon.com
```

**STEP 2: Make sure that the key pair file is read-only.**

LINUX:
To make the key pair file read-only execute this command: `chmod 400 QARTH.pem` while in the same directory as the file.

WINDOWS:
Commands to run on a Windows system (as administrator) to make a key pair read-only and satisfy `ssh`:

Note replace %USERNAME% with your user name.

```
REM Disable inheritance on QARTH.pem
icacls QARTH.pem /inheritance:d

REM Delete "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" from having any rights
icacls QARTH.pem /remove "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users"

REM Delete "BUILTIN\Users" from having any rights
icacls QARTH.pem /remove "BUILTIN\Users"

REM Grant Read-Only rights to me
icacls QARTH.pem /GRANT:R "%USERNAME%:(R)"
```

**STEP 3: Make sure that you are using the correct username for the EC2 AMI:**

Usernames for popular EC2 AMIs:

- For Amazon Linux 2 or the Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
- For a Centos AMI, the user name is centos.
- For a Debian AMI, the user name is admin or root.
- For a Fedora AMI, the user name is ec2-user or fedora.
- For a RHEL AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
- For a SUSE AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.
- For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu.
- Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don't work, check with the AMI provider.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Could you elaborate, please, on what you mean by the "wrong key pair" ? I'm using the `pem` file that downloads automatically when you generate a key pair on the AWS dashboard. Also, is there some Windows alternative to chmod that I should be using? `chmod 400` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Are you running under Windows? Which version? Which ssh client? When I said wrong key pair, I meant wrong key pair. If you have two key pairs and use the wrong one you will get that error message. So you are either using the wrong key pair or the file permissions on the key pair are wrong (read-only is required). `chmod` does not do enough to make a Windows file read-only when run from Windows. I will edit my answer with the commands to make a key pair read-only on Windows, but I need to know the version of Windows first.

Comment: Cool, no problem. This is Windows 7 Ultimate. Based on your clarification, I'm pretty certain that this is the right file, so it must be the read-only issue. I've done this successfully on a Windows 10 machine, but not a Win7 one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed instructions. Unfortunately, after going through this procedure twice, there has been no change in the output. Even after doing all this, it still looks like the mod is 644, and the error output is the same.

Comment: How are you determining 644 permissions? This means one of the commands failed. Did any of the commands report an error? Double check. I just correct the file name in my last command.

Comment: Thanks. I did spot that error in the file name, and corrected it the second time I tried this. I am running the commands you've suggested in an administrator windows command prompt. When I go to do SSH though, I need to use GitBash. From GitBash, which uses a Linux style interface, it appears that the mod is 644

Comment: sorry, just realized I didn't fully answer your question. I had an error because of a typo and corrected it. Other than that, all the commands say "Successfully processed 1 files"

Comment: Use Windows Explorer and look at the properties for the key pair file. You can also set / change security on the file. If Windows Explorer shows the file as read-only, then GitBash has a problem on Windows. I don't know as I don't use GitBash. I use Windows tools on Windows. I recommend Bitvise for SSH to AWS when running on Windows.

Comment: One last item. Are you specifying the correct user name to connect to your EC2 instance? You will get the same (or similar) error message for the wrong user name.

Comment: I've checked the instructions on AWS; it appears that "ubuntu" is the correct user name when connecting to an Ubuntu 64 bit image. This is the user name that I'm using on other computers when successfully connecting, as well.

I'll have to try your other suggestions tomorrow. Thank you very much for all of your help

Comment: I modified my answer. Please post the output of STEP 1 in your question (Not as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR**
>   Try using the manually generated SSH key pair via AWS Console

Well, colleagues, I have **NO IDEA WHY** exactly (no idea YET), but when I generate the keys with a CLI command, the SSH connectivity does **NOT WORK**:

```
aws --region us-east-1 ec2 create-key-pair --key-name "KeyPair"
```

BUT, when I am creating the SSH key pai manually using the **AWS Console** it works perfectly fine:

```
1. Go to AWS Console
2. EC2 :: Network & Security (in left menu) :: Key Pairs :: Create Key Pair
3. <As soon as I am specifying the name of a key pair Amazon downloads the keys into a default download directory>
4. chmod 400 KeyPair.pem
5. ssh -i ./SSHKeys.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-162-166-40.compute-1.amazonaws.com
6. ENJOY!
```

**P.S.** I am pretty sure I have messed up something during the response copy-paste from a CLI ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permission of key file

```
sudo chmod 400 rsa_key_file_name.pem
```

put you key file name and enter and you are done